# How to change the view of a list item

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django, and within my models.py, I created some lists. My project is about car entry and exit control. So I created a specific list for when the user requests a car, it has the following states: "Waiting, Confirmed or Denied". I need to know how to change these states when certain events happen, such as the request is denied or approved.

This is a part of my models.py code:

```
SITUATION = [
("WAITING", "WAITING"), ("DENIED", "DENIED"), ("CONFIRMED", "CONFIRMED")
]

class RequestCar (models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField (primary_key = True)
    secretary = models.CharField (max_length = 15, choices = SECRETARIES)
    dateTimeReserve = models.DateTimeField (auto_now_add = True, db_column = 'date_time_reserve')
    dateExit = models.DateTimeField (verbose_name = 'Expected Exit Date', db_column = 'exit_date')
    exitTime = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Expected Exit Time', choices = TIME)
    requester = models.CharField (max_length = 50)
    email = models.EmailField ()
    numPassengers = models.IntegerField (verbose_name = 'Number of Passengers', db_column = 'num_pasage')
    reason = models.CharField (max_length = 150)
    itinerary = models.CharField (max_length = 50)
    expectationTime = models.CharField (max_length = 7, verbose_name = 'What is the expected time of absence?',choices = TIME)
    driverAwait = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Does the driver wait in place?',choices = DRIVER_AGUARD, db_column = 'driver_guard')
    office = models.FileField (verbose_name = 'office', upload_to = 'media /', blank = True)
    situation = models.CharField (max_length = 10, choices = SITUATION, default = "WAITING")


class ResponseRequest (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField (primary_key = True)
    accepted = models.NullBooleanField ()
    car = models.ForeignKey (Car, on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column = 'car')
    driver = models.ForeignKey (Driver, on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column = 'driver')
    request = models.ForeignKey (RequestCar, on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_column = 'request')
```

My views.py:

```
def replyGeneral Request (request, template_name = "answer / reply_request.html"):
    form = AnswerRequestForms (request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid ():
        form.save ()
        return redirect ('listGeneral Request')
    else:
        form = AnswerRequestForms ()
    return render (request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

---

Basically, I want when the request is accepted, the situation changes from "waiting" to "confirmed".
OBS: There are other classes in both models and views, but I don't think it's necessary for this question.

Comment: Is `AnswerRequestForms` a `ModelForm` for the `RequestCar` model?

Comment: No, it's from ResponseRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AnswerRequestForms` is for a `ResponseRequest`, so when you save it, it returns the `ResponseRequest` instance you just created:

```
if form.is_valid():
    response_request = form.save()
    car_request = response_request.request
    car_request.situation = "CONFIRMED"
    car_request.save()
    return redirect(...)
```